# Share local collection between Threads in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have two methods as below

```
private void MethodB_GetId()
        {
            //Calling Method A constinuosly in different thread
            //Let's say its calling for Id = 1 to 100
        }

        private void MethodA_GetAll()
        {
            List<string> lst;
            lock(_locker)
            {
                lst = SomeService.Get(); //This get return all 100 ids in one shot.
                //Some other processing and then return result.
            }
        }
```

Now client is calling MethodB_GetById continuously for fetching data for id: 1 to 100 randomly. (It require some of data from these 100 Ids, not all data)

MethodA_GetAll get all data from network may be cache or database in one shot. and return whole collection to method B, then method B extract record in which it is interested.

Now if MethodA_GetAll() makes GetALL() times multiple times and fetching same records will be useless. so i can put a lock around it one thread is fetching record then other will be blocked.

Let's When MethodA_GetAll called by Id = 1 acquire lock and all others are waiting for lock to be released.

What i want is one data is available by any one thread just don't make call again.

Solution option:
1. Make List global to that class and thread safe. (I don't have that option)

I require some how thread 1 tell all other threads that i have record don't go fetching record again.

something like

```
lock(_locker && Lst!=null) //Not here lst is local to every thread
{
   //If this satisfy then only fetch records 
}
```

Please excuse me for poorly framing question. I have posted this in little hurry.

Comment: based on "i have record don't go fetching record again" > `ConcurrentQueue<T>`?

Comment: Either Lazy or Concurrent Collection as described...

Comment: That i know i can use concurrent collection, But don't want to specify anything global. I want collection which is local to a method but shared by all threads.... which may not be possible as per my understanding but just checking if anything exist to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create a threadsafe cache. One way to do this is to use [`Lazy<t>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netframework-4.8).

Here's an example for a cache of type `List<string>`:

```
public sealed class DataProvider
{
    public DataProvider()
    {
        _cache = new Lazy<List<string>>(createCache);
    }

    public void DoSomethingThatNeedsCachedList()
    {
        var list = _cache.Value;

        // Do something with list.

        Console.WriteLine(list[10]);
    }

    readonly Lazy<List<string>> _cache;

    List<string> createCache()
    {
        // Dummy implementation.
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
    }
}
```

When you need to access the cached value, you just access `_cache.Value`. If it hasn't yet been created, then the method you passed to the `Lazy<T>`'s constructor will be called to initialise it. In the example above, this is the `createCache()` method.

This is done in a threadsafe manner, so that if two threads try to access the cached value simultaneously when it hasn't been created yet, one of the threads will actually end up calling `createCache()` and the other thread will be blocked until the cached value has been initialised.

Answer (score 0):

You can try double-check-locking `lst`:

```
private List<string> lst;

private void MethodA_GetAll()
{
    if (lst == null)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            if (lst == null)
            {
                // do your thing
            }
        }
    }
}
```